# Understanding the implementation of Y-Combinator

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, y-combinator

I would like to understand in mint detail please how we managed to get from the lambda calculus expression of Y-combinator :

```
Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))
```

to the following implementation (in Scala) :

```
def Y[A, B](f: (A => B) => A => B): A => B = (x: A) => f(Y(f))(x)
```

I am pretty new to functional programming but I have a decent understanding of lambda calculus and how the substitution process works. I am having however some hard time understanding how did we get from the formal expression to the implementation.

Besides, I would love to know how to tell the **type** and **number** of **arguments** of my function and its **return type** of whatever **lambda**?

Comment: Where did you find the implementation? It looks like it "cheats" by recursing directly in Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that what you wrote is not an implementation of the `Y` combinator. The "`Y` combinator" is a specific "fixed-point combinator" in the λ-calculus. A "fixed-point" of a term `g` is just a point `x` such that,

```
g(x) = x
```

A "fixed-point combinator" `F` is a term that can be used to "produce" fix points. That is, such that,

```
g(F(g)) = F(g)
```

The term `Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))` is one among many that obeys that equation, i.e. it is such that `g(Y(g)) = Y(g)` in the sense that one term can be reduced to the other. This property means such terms, including `Y` can be used to "encode recursion" in the calculus.

Regarding typing note that the `Y` combinator cannot be typed in the simply typed λ-calculus. Not even in polymorphic calculus of system F. If you try to type it, you get a type of "infinite depth". To type it, you need recursion at the type level. So if you want to extend e.g. simply typed λ-calculus to a small functional programming language you provide `Y` as a primitive.

You're not working with λ-calculus though, and your language already comes with recursion. So what you wrote is a straightforward definition for fixed-point "combinator" in Scala. Straightforward because being a fixed-point follows (almost) immediately from the definition.

```
Y(f)(x) = f(Y(f))(x)
```

is true for all `x` (and it is a pure function) therefore,

```
Y(f) = f(Y(f))
```

which is the equation for fixed-points. Regarding the inference for the type of `Y` consider the equation `Y(f)(x) = f(Y(f))(x)` and let,

```
f : A => B
Y : C => D
```

since `Y : C => D` takes `f : A => B` as an input  then,

```
C = A => B
```

since `Y f : D` is an input of `f : A => B` then

```
D = A
```

and since the output `Y f : D` is the same as that of `f(Y(f)) : B` then

```
D = B
```

thus far we have,

```
Y : (A => A) => A
```

since `Y(f)` is applied to `x`, `Y(f)` is a function, so

```
A = A1 => B1
```

for some types `A1` and `B1` and thus,

```
Y : ((A1 => B1) => (A1 => B1)) => A1 => B1
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Comment: great answer. I especially like the precision of your writing: "type of infinite depth" is precise and clear, the usual "infinite type" is confusing and vague.

Answer (score 5):

First, the Scala code is a long way of writing:

```
def Y[A, B](f: (A => B) => A => B): A => B = f(Y(f))
```

Here, `f` is partially applied. (It looks like the code author chose to use a lambda to make this more explicit.)

Now, how do we arrive at this code? [Wikipedia notes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) that `Y f = f (Y f)`. Expanding this to something Scala-like, we have `def Y(f) = f(Y(f))`. This wouldn't work as a definition in lambda calculus, which doesn't allow direct recursion, but it works in Scala. To make this into valid Scala, we need to add types. Adding a type to `f` results in:

```
def Y(f: (A => B) => A => B) = f(Y(f))
```

Since `A` and `B` are free, we need to make them type parameters:

```
def Y[A, B](f: (A => B) => A => B) = f(Y(f))
```

Since it's recursive, we need to add a return type:

```
def Y[A, B](f: (A => B) => A => B): A => B = f(Y(f))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would love also to know how did we infer that f is of type  (A => B) => A => B ?

Comment: Are you sure the version by @ecdhe is t equivalent to yours? In a call-by-value setting the eta-reduction does change semantics. I don't think this version should work, unless you eta-expand inside the Y on the right hand side.